# Switch between models based on partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm experimenting more with ASP.Net MVC. Here's my scenario. I have a parent view that currently has no model. I have a drop down that gets the html for a partial view.

I have two options and two partial views. Each partial view has it's own model.  My problem is I'm trying to send the model of the partial view being used to an action to generate data to populate a textarea. Model is nothing special just a bunch of properties of string type. Also I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do the partials both just have a single editorfor, but use different models.  Thoughts?

I feel like I'm missing something that MVC can handle. A better way to do this.  Currently I'm just sending the value of the textbox. But I want the whole partial view model.

jQuery:

```
$('#options').change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.get('/Home/MyAction1/' + id, function (data) {
                    $('#mypartial').html(data);
                });
            });


$('#mypartial').on('change', '.texboxes', function() {
                var value = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/MyAction2',
                    data: { 'value': value },
                    type: "get",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (s) {
                        $('.textarea1').html(s);
                    }                       
                });
            });
```

Parent View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select id="options">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mypartial">
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 pull-right">
    @Html.TextArea("test", new { @class = "textarea1" })
</div>
```

Partial View 1

```
@model MyModel
@{
    @Html.EditorForModel()    
}
```

Partial View 2

```
@model MyModel2
@{
    @Html.EditorForModel()    
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Hey again.  I got those templates to work, thanks again.  Basically the view has multiple textboxes.  I want to be able to send the whole model to process the data and generate a new string to populate a textarea.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Then you partials should be forms and if you want to post back the form using ajax then serialize the form - `data: $('form').serialize(),`. But its hard to understand what your really trying to achieve with this and unless you keep reparsing the validator you will also lose client side validation

Comment: Hmm well I'm not really trying to validate on the textboxes.  Free to enter anything.

Comment: So maybe something like this you're saying..  Then adjust my ajax to do a post with serializing the form..    `@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction2", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform", @class = "myformclass" }))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}' `

Comment: `$.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/MyAction2',
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (s) {
                            $('.textarea1').html(s);
                        }                       
                    });`

Comment: Something like that, and include a `<button type="button" ..>` and handle its click event to do the ajax. (but please use `url: '@Url.Action(''MyAction2", "Home")',` - don't hard code url's)

Comment: Cool looks like it works.  Just have one issue.  Because I have 2 models/partial view.  Looks like an overload of the post doesn't work.  I get an ambiguous error.  Thought I'd give it a shot to send in an object instead, but that didn't seem to work. `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction2(MyModel)
{
    return Content("test", "text/html");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction2(MyModel2)
{
    return Content("test", "text/html");
}`

Comment: No you will need 2 separate post methods with different names. You will just need to change the url based on the option you have selected, or if your generating the forms using `@Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName)` then you could just use `url = $('form').attr('action');`

Comment: Ahh ok so it doesn't support overloading and I can just use separate actions for the different forms and specify it in the form.  Works!  Thanks.